# Unresolved External Symbol (again)

Tags: c++, unresolved-external

I have no idea why the following gives me: *"error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 'struct Win32Vars_t win32' (?win32@@3UWin32Vars_t@@A)"* If I start a new project and create this header file it compiles fine. I'm also creating another struct similar to this and it also compiles just fine (although instead of "extern -variablename-" it's a static. Should this not work?

win_local.h

```
#ifndef __WIN_LOCAL_H__
#define __WIN_LOCAL_H__

#include <windows.h>

void System_CreateConsole(void);

typedef struct {

    HWND hWnd;
    HINSTANCE hInstance;

} Win32Vars_t;

extern Win32Vars_t win32;

#endif
```

What it with the cryptic @@3U message in parenthesis?

Sorry for creating yet another post about unresolved externals. I did do some reading before hand and tried various things. From what I read, this is C way of doing things but should still work in C++. And yes, .h file is set to compile C/C++.

Comment: You don't define `win32` anywhere, do you (no, you don't).

Comment: As for the weird characters in the name, read about [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: In the header you promised that there'll be a Win32Vars_t structure provided named win32. Then you did not supply it and the linker told you just that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because an "extern" variable is declared but not defined: you're only telling the compiler that somewhere else in your code, there's a "Win32Vars_t win32" variable and it can use it.

With only the "extern", no symbol is allocated, that's why you're getting an unresolved symbol.

That means you must define it somewhere else in your code. The usual pattern is to use an "extern" in header file, so every other file including that header will be able to "see" the variable and in a source file (something.c) define the variable, something like this:

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

extern int foo;

#endif
```

.c

```
#include "foo.h"

int foo;
```

You can find more information about external variables here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. I do actually have it defined somewhere else, but I just realized an issue with that. Thanks for jogging my memory! Just learned about typedef's and structs yesterday... sorry for the redundant question.